# Visual Studio 2017 disable folder namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to disable namespace generation in Visual Studio 2017 using C# language? to make it work as visual basic does without namespaces

Comment: No, in C#, everything lives in a namespace.

Comment: I was asking because in xamarin studio if you create a folder inside your project and then you add a class, the name of the folder will not be the namespace for the class, the class will live in the main namespace as the assembly

Comment: That isn't clear from your question. Please update.

Comment: You could make your own template for class files or [edit the existing one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx#Anchor_1) assuming it works the same in VS 2017.

Comment: @Crowcoder that wouldn't help, the IDE generates the namespace on the fly. I agree with OP, it can be very annoying. Unfortunately there is no way to disable it as of VS2017 15.6.1.

Comment: You could accomplish it with a Wizard template but you'd have to weigh the effort of development against just changing the namespace of new classes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an extension called **ReSharper**, which is a JetBrains product, however this (unfortunately) costs, though there is at the time of writing, the option for a free 30 day trial.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/